# count(1) and distinct behaviour in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Imagine a table:

```
name   age
John   20
Sam    60
Dave   30
John   15
```

I want to check count of distinct names, I query the table like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), DISTINCT(name)
FROM table
GROUP BY 2
```

But I get:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"
> Position: 18

But when I use:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(name), COUNT(1)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

I do get what's expected:

```
John 2
Sam  1
Dave 1
```

Is there a reason why the first query is not working or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` and it always has to come after the SELECT keyword. But combined with `group by` it's completely unnecessary to begin with. Btw: `count(1)` is actually slightly _slower_ in Postgres than `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

The distinct here is not required. GROUP BY means 'group by a distinct set of values'
so

```
SELECT COUNT(*), name
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

Will give you the result I think you want.